# Equation - brackets

Tags: equations

How can I improve brakets in this equation please?

```
\begin{equation}\label{E}
E_0^{(1)} = \expval{\frac{e'^2}{|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|}}{\Phi}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
And please, what is wrong here? I think that in the end should be {\Phi }\, but it is mistake by compilation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{E}
E_0^{(1)} = 4 \pi e'^2 \expval**{\frac{1}{|\vec{r}_2|} \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{m=-l}^l \left(\frac{|\vec{x}^{(1)}|}{|\vec{x}^{(2)}|} \right)^l \Phi }\\
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\left...\right`? P.S. I usually write `\vec{r}_1` because of space.

Comment: Please provide a compilable example. Where does the `\expval` command come from?

Comment: Off-topic: One should probably write `\vec{r}_1` instead of `\vec{r_1}`, and `\vec{r}_2` instead of `\vec{r_2}`.

Comment: Instead of editing an existing query to pose what's essentially a new question, you should post a new query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the `physics` package, then it looks like you have to pass two `*` arguments to `\expval` to allow it to auto-resize the brackets.

As for your second equation, it is missing an argument. You had `\expval**{stuff \Phi}`, but you need to provide another argument: `\expval**{stuff}{\Phi}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{E}
E_0^{(1)} = \expval**{\frac{e'^2}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|}}{\Phi}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{E2}
E_0^{(1)} = 4 \pi e'^2 \expval**{\frac{1}{|\vec{r}_2|} \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l \left(\frac{|\vec{x}^{(1)}|}{|\vec{x}^{(2)}|} \right)^l}{\Phi}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Please, can I have one more question - I editted my origin question.

Comment: @Elisabeth The solution was simple, so I also updated my answer. If you happen to have more problems it's advisable, as Mico said, to ask a new question instead of editing an old question.

Comment: You should definitely remove the double-backslash stuff at the end of the `equation` environments. Also, the `\limits` directives are redundant; all they do is create code clutter.

Comment: @Mico Oops, I forgot those there. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 9):

I do not know where `\expval` comes from but with `braket` you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{E}
E_0^{(1)} = \Braket{\Phi | \frac{e'^2}{\left|\vec r_1 - \vec r_2\right|} | \Phi}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]